# CSS Menu in IE7/8

Tags: menu, css, navigation

Im having issues with a drop down menu system in IE7 and 8.

It works flawlessly in Chrome and FF, however in IE7 and 8 for some reason it doesn't apply some of the styling and ends up being misplaced in the browser.

You can view it here:

http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk/menutest

As said, it works fine in Chrome, however I am struggling to get it to work properly, or even just BETTER in IE7.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an explicit width on `.side_nav ul li`:

```
.side_nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 173px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

For extra protection, you might want to add a `clear: both` and a `text-align: left` property (shown in the above example).

Comment: +1 Or you can add `width:173x` for `.side_nav ul` instead `.side_nav ul li`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display: block;
```

to your

```
.side_nav ul li
```

Comment: Done that but still getting the same result :(